# Gnuplot buttons greyed out

Tags: button, gnuplot, ubuntu-18.04

For years, I have used gnuplot from shell scripting and from the command line like this:

```
$ printf "1 2\n2 4\n3 6\n" > data.txt
$ echo "plot \"data.txt\" using 1:2" | gnuplot -persist
$
```

This gives an interactive plot with functioning buttons to toggle the grid, replot, apply autoscale and so on. Under my fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04, these buttons are grey and disabled when gnuplot is operated like above. Alternatively:

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 2    last modified 2017-11-01 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2017
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'wxt'
gnuplot> plot "data.txt" using 1:2
gnuplot>
```

This gives functioning buttons.

```
$ gnuplot -e "plot \"data.txt\" using 1:2"
$
```

This gives grey, disabled buttons again. How do I get the buttons to function in the first, scriptable method?

*** Edit below **********************
On at least one of my 14.04 machines the gnuplot version is indeed rather old: Version 4.6 patchlevel 4 last modified 2013-10-02. Using `gnuplot -e "plot \"data.txt\" using 1:2; pause mouse close; exit" &` keeps the buttons enabled... but so does `echo "plot  \"data.txt\" using 1:2; pause mouse close;"  | gnuplot &` on both Gnuplot versions. So thanks for your answer.

Comment: Was your old version of gnuplot by any chance 4.4 or older? That version had slightly non-standard behavior for the `persist` option when used with the `wxt` terminal, see [Persistent confusion about gnuplot -persist](http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/Persistent-confusion-about-gnuplot-persist-td18833.html). What happens when you try `gnuplot -e "plot \"data.txt\" using 1:2; pause mouse close; exit" &`?

Comment: If you turn this into an answer I will flag it as such.

Comment: The same problem persists even for Gnuplot version 5.2. The alternative given by @user8153 works like a charm!

Comment: Not any more - the link is dead!